# MS Access Network Interruption

Tags: ms-access, networking

I have an MS access system on a network with 15 users. The Front end is installed on users C:\ and BE on a mapped drive X:.The front end is about 8 meg, backend around 25.

Since day 1, one user constantly (every 30 mins at best) and some other users have a network interrupted error. Apart from being quite annoying to the users, this causes a temporarily masked/hidden issue where update queries run without error  on 2 tables but do not update actually update/insert data.

A compact and repair resolves the issue, but is not feasible to run daily as users have the system open throughout the day. This is such a headache that I've had to write code to check that the data has been written after each query is run to detect if the issue is present.

Both myself and IT are 3rd parties to the business and are in the difficult opposing positions of  "its your the network" and "its your database". Thankfully its all calm and peaceful but its not getting a solution for the client.

I've installed MS access FE/BE systems on over a hundred networks over the last 10 years and only ever seen the same issue on a peer to peer network. I'm aware that Access is very picky about network stability, but am faced with users who don't believe that there is a problem with the network as their email works and the internet radio doesn't drop out.

What I'm hoping to get assistance with here is either a tool / method that can  test a network for stability / robustness with MS access and prove either one of us right/wrong with MS access or perhaps some advice on how I could move forward on this deadlock.

Thanks

Comment: Affected users don't have power saving enabled on their network cards?

Comment: I would check if this is network or Access first: schedule a task to read some network file and log results every, let's say, 20 and then 40 minutes. If this is network issue, the task will fail to read, which means that something wrong with network.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys - no success on the power saving settings (non enabled). Our next step is to run an alternate cat cable, then alternate switch ports.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar instance with damaged cables.  A client of mine had mice that chewed through part of the cable, causing an intermittent interruption.  Also, in another case, a cubicle wall was on top of the network cable (poor cable installation) and causing a short.

In order to bypass Access's need for constant network connection, I have my systems create local temporary tables for any view, and a local, 1-record table for any detail form that they are actively editing.  Once they hit 'save' it runs the update query, and once done, no active connection with the server is needed again. It allows me to run much faster access systems, and eliminated the need for stable wireless or Ethernet.  It does require quite a bit of structure change at first - as you will have to insert code to create local temporary tables in the FE file, and also code in an UPDATE Sequence in the AFTERUPDATE Form events too - but the time that it is has saved me and my users has been tremendous.

To put in in perspective, i have 1200+ users in the same Access database in a given week (sometimes 400+ in a day) and since they only 'pull' data from the server to make local table copies, there are only a handful of connections at any one time.  My users can now dock and undock from their desks without needing to close the database.